# how to calculate due date in django based on existing date

Tags: python, django

How do i calculate the due date from this model based on the date renewed.
i want the due date to be 5 years after the date Renewed.

I'm pretty stuck.
I need help.

This is my models.py file in Django

````
    def get_deadline():
    return dateRenewed() + timedelta(days=1825)

    class Trademark(models.Model):
        trademarkName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        trademarkClass = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        acknowledgeDoc = models.FileField(upload_to='acknowledge_docs', default='default.jpg')
        acceptanceDoc = models.FileField(upload_to='acceptance_docs/', default='default.jpg')
        cert = models.FileField(upload_to='trademark_cert/', default='default.jpg')
        renewalDoc = models.FileField(upload_to='renewalDocs', default='default.jpg')
        dateRenewed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
        duedate = models.DateTimeField(default=get_deadline)
        uploadedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timedelta` to add the years:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

delta = timezone.timedelta(days=365*5) # create a timedelta object

duedate = dateRenewed + delta
```

This doesn't handle leap years, though.

**Accounting for leap years**

The above code always counts 365 days for every year. But if you want to account for leap years, you'll need to add an extra day for every leap year:

```py
import calendar
from django.utils import timezone

year_1 = dateRenewed.year
year_2 = year_1 + 5
leap_days = calendar.leapdays(year_1, year_2) # count leap days between two years
total_days = (365 * 5) + leap_days

delta = timezone.timedelta(days=total_days)

duedate = dateRenewed + delta
```

Comment: Will this be done in the models.py file?

Comment: @DanielAzubuine If you want to use this value to save in the model object, then put it inside the `save()` method of the model ([as shown here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.

It's by using

```
    @property
    def shelfLife(self):
        return self.dateRenewed + datetime.timedelta(days=365*5)
```